# Pluralizing abbreviations where the noun is not the last word

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

For abbreviations - both acronyms and initialisms - where the last word in the abbreviation is the noun, I'm accustomed to adding an 's' with no apostrophe (e.g. ATMs), as described in the answer to this question: [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

But how do you pluralize abbreviations where the noun is not the last word? E.g. 'Point of Presence' (POP)

I can see how 'POPs' could read 'Point of Presences', when the intention is 'Points of Presence.'

Comment: Similar: [What is the plural of the abbreviation of “multiplicity automaton”, “MA” or “MAs”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322797) Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a general principle that applies to cases like this. I think if it is pronounced as "pop," the plural would indeed be "POPs." More closely related: [Is there any plural for the acronym “POC” ("proof of concept")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23589)

Comment: It doesn't address the position of the object in the acronym, but this may be of help: http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/apostrophes_show_plural_of_abbreviations.htm

Comment: If I'm writing out each word, I pluralise the words as separate. If I were to treat them as a lump, I'd also hyphenate. In their short form, I'd toss the s on at the end.

Comment: Related question (and answer): [When pluralizing a hyphenated acronym, where does the "s" land in the acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341760/when-pluralizing-a-hyphenated-acronym-where-does-the-s-land-in-the-acronym/341796#341796)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Virtually always, the *s* follows the full abbreviation even when a word other than the last one is the proper plural. Paul Brians in *Common Errors in English Usage* cites

> [POWs, RPMs, WMDs](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/rbi.html)

This style is also recommended in the AP Style Guide, so it is what you will see in most newspapers. But not all.

The other option is to discard the *s* altogether, as in this news story from the Cleveland-area *News-Herald*:

> [Byrd had five home runs and 19 RBI in 34 games](http://www.news-herald.com/article/HR/20160604/SPORTS/160609773).

This is certainly not a typo. Many commentators prefer this, but it is simply that, a preference. As a former editor at ESPN, I had this discussion many times with writers and other editors, many insisting that there is only one right way to do it. Clearly, that is not true. If you prefer the *s*, use it, but only after the entire abbreviation. Nobody, but nobody, uses *RsBI*.

Comment: OK, I've fixed, but I haven't mentioned Schudel because the decision to include an "s" or not would not be his decision--it would be the editor's.

Comment: As far as I know, no one uses _MspH_ or _MPHs_ for _miles per hour_, which suggests that there is a degree of fluidity in the way people apply the "add an _s_ at the end" rule or the "don't add an _s_ at the end" rule in dealing with initialisms. One important variable, I suspect, is whether the initialism is capped or lowercase: plural _rpm_ or _mph_ seems much clearer to me than plural _rpms_ or _mphs_. But you are certainly correct that people never place the plural after the initial of the word that is plural in its whole-word form.

Comment: @SvenYargs - rpm and mph are different, in that the initialisation is *based* on the plural noun, rather than a single-noun-based initialisation being pluralised.

Comment: @SvenYargs These are considered measurement units. There is an infinity possible decimal values for each unit, and there is only a single case where it is singular - this makes it implicitly plural. Another reason is that adding unnecessary 's' can change the unit - if 'meters' is abbreviated to 'ms', it becomes 'milliseconds'.