# Use (or not) of appostrohe when making an abbreviated plural

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, apostrophe

We had a discussion the other day that needs settling.
I am a medical student and in our "industry" we use a lot of three letter abbreviations such as: CPR (Cardiac Pulmonary Resuscitation), PUN (Patient Unmet Need), PEN (Practitioner Educational Need) etc. You get the message.
Now, the other day our tutor wrote in a presentation: PENs, PUNs, CPRs and I argued (who am I to argue with the tutor?) that it should be PEN's, PUN's CPR's as we are pluralising an abbreviation.
What is the rule (if any) about pluralising abbreviations?
Dan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pluralizing abbreviations where the noun is not the last word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334097/pluralizing-abbreviations-where-the-noun-is-not-the-last-word) Or even more to the point: [What is the best way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Comment: The answer below is worth preserving. It is succinct and has several good sources.

Answer (score 0):

Both conventions are used in different contexts, and I've seen a lot of instances of both.

Although [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Representing_plurals_and_possessives) is not an authoritative reference, it does contain links to references.

> There is a question about how to pluralize acronyms. Often a writer will add an 's' following an apostrophe, as in "PC's". However, Kate Turabian, writing about style in academic writings,[50] allows for an apostrophe to form plural acronyms "**only when an abbreviation contains internal periods or both capital and lowercase letters**". Turabian would therefore prefer "DVDs" and "URLs" and "Ph.D.'s". The Modern Language Association[51] and American Psychological Association[52][53] **prohibit apostrophes** from being used to pluralize acronyms regardless of periods (so "compact discs" would be "CDs" or "C.D.s"), **whereas** the New York Times style guide **requires an apostrophe when pluralizing all abbreviations** regardless of periods (preferring "PC's, TV's and VCR's").[54]
>
> Possessive plurals that also include apostrophes for mere pluralization and periods appear especially complex: for example, the C.D.'s' labels (the labels of the compact discs). In some instances, however, an apostrophe may increase clarity: for example, if the final letter of an abbreviation is S, as in SOS's (although abbreviations ending with S can also take -es, e.g. SOSes), or when pluralizing an abbreviation that has periods.[55][56]

Comment: Hello, jl. Please be aware that a lot of questions have already been asked and answered on ELU; duplicating these makes things harder to search out.