# What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter? Or a word used as a word ('mention' usage)? (another apostrophe question)

Tags: grammatical-number, alphabet

When writing (a blog post, script, etc..) what is the proper way to indicate two or more instances of a single letter? For instance, in Monty Python's *Bookshop Sketch*:

> C: I wonder if you might have a copy of "Rarnaby Budge"?
>
> P: No, as I say, we're right out of Edmund Wells!
>
> C: No, not Edmund Wells - Charles Dikkens.
>
> P: (pause - eagerly) Charles Dickens??
>
> C: Yes.
>
> P: (excitedly) You mean "Barnaby Rudge"!
>
> C: No, "Rarnaby Budge" by Charles Dikkens.  That's Dikkens with two Ks, the
>      well-known Dutch author.
>
> P: (slight pause) No, well we don't have "Rarnaby Budge" by Charles Dikkens
>      with two Ks, the well-known Dutch author, and perhaps to save time I
>      should add that we don't have "Karnaby Fudge" by Darles Chickens, or
>      "Farmer of Sludge" by Marles Pickens, or even "Stickwick Stapers" by Farles
>      Wickens with **four M's** and a silent Q!!!!!  Why don't you try W. H. Smith's?
>
> C: Ah did, They sent me here.

I had always believed that plural never uses an apostrophe before the 's' (it's only used for possession), but I have rarely seen in written material the format "four Ms". (On a side note, whoever wrote [this transcript](http://www.skepticfiles.org/en001/bookshop.htm) also used "two Ks".)

On a side note, and perhaps this should be a separate question, if a Compact Disc is a CD, then two Compact Discs would be two CDs right? (I see "CD's" written *everywhere*)

Comment: for the second issue about the acronym CD, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym

Comment: The Canadian Government's "style manual" also lists some other cases where the apostrophe can be used. http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1.04

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The *Chicago Manual of Style*, one of the more widely used style guides in the United States, says:

> Capital letters used as words, numerals used as nouns, and abbreviations usually form the plural by adding *s*. To aid comprehension, lowercase letters form the plural with an apostrophe and an *s*.

So: *Dikkens with two Ks*, but *mind your p's and q's*. (And always *CDs*, unless you're talking about something the CD owns.)

Comment: And my Chicago Manual of Style sits in the basement of my parent's house about 4000km away. Thanks! :)

Comment: I like that this is purely a stylistic question, nobody is pretending it's the "correct way to do things". It does read a lot easier on the eyes if someone says "There are four i's in this sentence" than "There are four is in this sentence."

Comment: If someone starts the sentence by referring to multiples of the letter A or I, does the Chicago Manual of Style allow for an apostrophe to avoid confusion with the words "As" and "Is"?

Comment: Could the letter ‘s’ to the right of the apostrophe (or the apostrophe itself) in *p*’s be italicized in normal text? (The Penguin Guide to Punctuation recommends that the letter ‘p’ is italicized’.)

Answer (score 18):

Harbrace College Handbook 6th edition section 15d

> **Use the apostrophe and s to form the plural of letters, figures, symbols, and words referred to as words.**
>   *Examples* Congreve seldom crossed his t's, his 7's looked like 9's, and his and's were usually &'s.
>   **Note:** This apostrophe is sometimes omitted when there is no danger of ambiguity: the 1930's, or the 1930s; two B's and three C's, or two Bs and three Cs.

Answer (score 13):

This is one of those annoying exceptions to the general rule of never using an apostrophe to form plurals. It **can** be used when treating letters and numerals as nouns.

Personally, I only use it with lowercase letters where it is distinctly helpful (*mind your p's and q's*); for uppercase and numerals, adding a lowercase 's' should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

To form plural of letters, figures, symbols and abbreviations put the concerned thing in single inverted comma and then add s.

Comment: Like this: `'123's`?!