# What is the plural of "BlackBerry" (as in the handheld device)

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, brands

Is the plural of "[BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry)", *BlackBerries* or *BlackBerrys*?

I am asking, because I'm altering the underlying brand name to look more like the food and less like the product, leaving the reader to infer it from context.

Comment: Related question: what is the *opposite* of Blackberry? WhiteNut?

Comment: @JeffSahol My tech informs me it's an Apple.  (as in the manufacturer's popular phone)

Comment: I thought the opposite of Apple was "Real Computer" :P

Comment: The are not berries that are black, they're Blackberrys.

Comment: Related: [An answer to *Pluralization of proper nouns: regular or irregular?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/pluralization-of-proper-nouns-regular-or-irregular/81556#81556).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I appreciate [@senderle](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5545/senderle)'s choice to [consider the *New York Times*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/what-is-the-plural-of-blackberry-as-in-the-handheld-device/27143#27143) as a source for common usage.

However, I found the "proper" answer in a [BlackBerry Branding Guidelines](http://www.blackberry.com/app_includes/legal/pushmark/BlackBerryBrandingGuidelinesVersion40March%202007.pdf) PDF from 2007 (page 5):

> Avoid using the RIM Marks generically, as nouns or verbs and do not use them in the plural or possessive form.

and

> 3. Do not use the RIM Marks in plural or possessive form.
>      ✓ BlackBerry® smartphones
>      ✗ <strike>BlackBerrys, BlackBerries, BlackBerry’s</strike>

This is in agreement with what [some other answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/what-is-the-plural-of-blackberry-as-in-the-handheld-device/27141#27141) have suggested.

Comment: Any trademark holder will tell you that. That doesn't mean that's how people use it in the real world.

Comment: That advice specifically concerns the use of "BlackBerry" as a _trademark_. Legally speaking, you cannot trademark a noun or a verb; only adjectival usage is trademarked. [Here's an overview of trademark law.](http://www.hro.com/files/publications/HRO%20Publications/Intellectual%20Property/trademarklaw.pdf) My sense is that unless you work for Research in Motion, you probably don't care whether you're using _BlackBerry_ in a trademarkable way.

Comment: +1 this should be the correct answer and it's as official as it gets.

Comment: @serderle I don't think my answer suggested that I don't know what a trademark is. It uses the term "RIM Marks" and refers to a page that is entirely about trademarks. I was actually assuming some knowledge about trademarks when I offered this as an alternative authority. There's the common usage, which you covered, and then there's the "official" format from the horse's mouth. The question doesn't specify, so I delivered the latter for balance.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize you personally -- it just galls me to think that corporate lawyers are somehow dictating the rules of English usage.

Comment: @senderle - and importantly if people start using Blackberry generically it becomes like 'fax' 'xerox' and 'kleenex' and loses it's trademark status. Although, right now, RIM would be overjoyed to be popular enough to become generic!

Comment: I wish there was a similar guide for Twitter.  Namely past and future tense..

Answer (score 11):

I would write *Blackberries* rather than *Blackberrys*. The latter looks like a terrible spelling mistake. For most situations, altering the brand name in this way won't matter.

However, if you're preparing a formal document and need to use the exact trademarked name, then you'll have to use a circumlocution such as *Blackberry devices* or *Blackberry phones*.

Comment: Isn't this case the same for acronyms? I mean saying "Blackberry's" would be fine, no?

Comment: By the way, I'd still go for your "Blackberry devices/phones" rather than saying Blackberrys (this one NEVER) or Blackberries. :D

Comment: @Alenanno, I would say no. *Blackberry's* looks just as wrong as the others to me. I'd only use the apostrophe here if the brand name itself is also an acronym.

Comment: Well I like your answer more for that second part, so I upvoted it. :)

Comment: @Alenanno, why would you pluralize with an apostrophe? Even an acronym? Nah.

Comment: @msh210: Regarding "Blackberry" I was not sure, but with acronyms it's the proper way to pluralize. This is true with dotted acronyms. If you find an established acronym that became a word, like CDs, then you can avoid the apostrophe.

Comment: @Alenanno: You'd write _CAPTCHA's_ as the plural of _CAPTCHA_? It looks so wrong — or like the possessive. _CAPTCHAs_ looks much better.

Comment: @msh210: I'm not sure, but that version is also used. I don't think there is a strict rule for this.

Comment: @Alenanno: That'd be called, ironically enough, the greengrocer's apostrophe.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Why ironically?

Comment: @Alenanno: Cause you can buy the vegetable form of blackberries from a greengrocer.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: lol I didn't think of that...

Comment: @Alenanno, why do you think it is correct to use an apostrophe to pluralise an acronym? This is common but I think there is no grammatical justification for it. My email package (Lotus Notes, don't get me started...) FORCES me to use it (if I type "CDs" it auto-'corrects' this to "Cds" - but "CD's" it leaves alone). But I know that I'm right and it is wrong...<g>

Comment: @AAT: I'm not sure whether there is some justification to do it, I haven't investigated, but there isn't any explicit prohibition or rule against it.

Comment: @Alenanno - I think we should keep apostrophes for their traditional roles of indicating possession and omission. There are a good many questions about apostrophes and plurals on here already: for example http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostroph. The concensus seems to be that plurals should *not* be formed with an apostrophe, with the (possible) exception of pluralising single letters (because "ps and qs" looks weird: although I would fix that particular example by going for "Ps and Qs").

Comment: [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym) it says that with dotted acronyms, the `'s` pluralization is acceptable. And [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/when-to-form-a-plural-with-an-apostrophe/) it says that you would write `M.A.'s` and `Ph.D.'s` **but** `MAs` and `PhD's`.

Answer (score 9):

I often turn to the *New York Times* for answers to questions like these. Search for "BlackBerrys" and "BlackBerries" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/06/22/us/22smartphones.html) and see what you find.

Well, ok, I'll just tell you: they exclusively use "BlackBerrys." And if it's good enough for the *New York Times*, it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

The technically correct plural of *Blackberry* would be *Blackberrys* because it's a proper name. Using an apostrophe, i.e. *Blackberry's*, is improper because it is neither a possession nor an acronym. You could get away with treating it like the fruit, i.e. *blackberries*, and nobody except a stickler for proper grammar would complain.

I didn't vote for @senderle's post because the New York Times isn't good for anything except lining a birdcage. ;-)

Comment: -1 The reason people post questions here is that they are trying to understand the proper grammar. Simply "getting away with" a grammatically vague or incorrect usage is the antithesis of this site. Additionally, there's no room for mudslinging in answers, in my opinion. Leave that out, or in the comments.

Comment: Ouch. But is your beef with their journalism or their copy-editing?

Comment: @roviuser The main point here is to know how to write Blackberry in plural. It does not matter if it is not grammatical.

Comment: This answer works for me.  "Look at all those people talking on their Blackberrys"