# How should I pluralize letters?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter? (another apostrophe question)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop)

Sometimes, it becomes necessary to refer to, for instance, the instances of the letter "A" in a document. When doing so, how should I format the plural letter? I have seen `A's`, `"A"s`, `"A"'s`, and `"A"es`. Is one of these the optimal formatting, or is it something else entirely?

I would like to ignore the option of rephrasing the sentence, if at all possible.

Comment: Darn it! I thought I'd *finally* found something to ask on EL&U that *wasn't* a duplicate. Sigh…

Comment: Timothy, in spite of duplication your question is rather more clear than the other, which is a bit roundabout.  Anyway, good try!

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the link to the other one, anyway.