# "Hail Mary", "Glory Be" in the plural

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter? (another apostrophe question)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop)

In the rosary, a Catholic sacramental composed of prayer beads, there is a short prayer concluding each decade called "Glory Be" ("Glory be to the Father, Son and Holy Spirit...").

Would the plural be *Glory Bes* or *Glory Be's*?

Likewise, do you say *10 Hail Marys*?

Comment: There really isn't a simple rule for apostrophe plural's. As soon as a phrase becomes frozen into a single word, somebody wants to treat it as an indeclinable item like _D_ or _∳_ or _♁_, and uses an apostrophe plural on it. Usage, as we say, varies.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Pardon?

Comment: To the two people who voted to close this as "Not Constructive", I respectfully suggest that you re-read the definition of that reason, and then kindly explain in which universe this question could even remotely be considered to fit under that definition. Really.

Comment: I bet somebody calls that an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

At http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/plurals.htm under 'Plurals and Apostrophes' is given the claimed rule 'to form the plural of a word-as-a-word, put the word cited in italics and add 's in non-italics'. This would lead to 10 *Glory Be*'s and 7 *Hail Mary*'s. Assuming that the use of excerpt-as-a-title is considered a close enough modelling of the use of word-as-a-word.