# Proper apostrophe usage?

Tags: american-english, apostrophe, letter-writing, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter? (another apostrophe question)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop)
>   [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not)

Take for example, you ask somebody is there's two of one letter in somebody's name.

I normally write:

> Two n's in Hannah?

Because this looks weird:

> Two ns in Hannah?

Is there an English rule that approves of this apostrophe usage? Do you do it? Am I wrong for thinking *ns* looks wierd?

Answer (score 1):

The British linguist David Crystal has written that the apostrophe ‘avoids an awkward juxtaposition of symbols, especially with plurals’. *ns* is one such case. Write it as *n’s*.