# “What is the plural form of the grades A-, A+, B+, etc.?”

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

It may appear pedantic but "all of them received **A minuses or As minus** grade", does not appear to make sense.

If a subset of students received the same grade on their reports, then should the grade  be pluralized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter? (another apostrophe question)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop)

Comment: You'd probably not shy from saying _A minuses_ out loud, so that's the order to write. Spelling it out avoids the punctuation dog's breakfast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with pluralizing *A minus* as *A minuses*, like any other word. In the abbreviated form, an apostrophe would be appropriate: *A−'s*.

Answer (score -1):

I would rephrase this as "They each received an A-."

Note: I originally said you could use "They all received an A-." Since the reason I tossed that out may be relevant, I'll explain why I changed it. To say "all" instead of "each" could mislead someone into thinking that the students received an A- *as a group*, rather than each of them individually earning an A-.

Comment: Not sure, but can we also say "they each received A minuses or As minus ."

Comment: @Mou: then each of them received several grades. It doesn't have the same meaning :)

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise it's only opinion.

Comment: You'd like me to cite a source stating why it's good to rephrase sentences to avoid awkward structure?

Comment: This answer, although helpful for learning English, does not answer the question, which asks for a plural form.

Comment: Except using a plural form in this fashion is cumbersome and will most likely confuse the reader. Therefore, I don't believe it should be suggested. If there's no graceful way to write a sentence as it is currently structured, a better structure should be sought instead of trying to force it. That being said, it is perhaps not my answer, but the question itself which belongs on ELL. The distinction is often difficult to make, especially when the person asking the question couldn't possibly know whether there is a rule that gives an answer: they wouldn't be asking otherwise.