# the plural of the name of the letter e is ees

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, morphology, irregular-plurals, letter-names

According to the wikipedia article of [letter e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E)

> The plural of the name of the letter e is **ees** (the plural of the
>   letter itself is rendered *E's, Es, e's, es*).

Therefore, is [*ees*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ees) then a regular plural formed from [-es](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-es#English)?

Comment: I think this question was already answered here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop

Comment: @AlexBennett my OP question is not answered there at all

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/e) licenses the plurals e's and es. The plural ees is more felicitous to the pronunciation. 'Regular plural' is merely a term invented to describe the common way plurals are formed, by adding an _s_, or _es_ on occasion. But words ending in a, e, i, u don't 'regularly' take -es to pluralise.

Comment: @ should ees then be categorized an irregular plural (as is geese)?