# How to pluralise an acronym?

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

How would you make the plural form of an acronym? For example, if you have two of Nintendo's game console, the DS.

Would you say, "I have two DSes," "I have two DSs," or something else?

Comment: Huh, I've always wondered this.