# Pluralizing acronyms: how to?

Tags: orthography, apostrophe, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Let's say we're talking about PLCs (programmable logic controllers)?  Or are they "PLC's"?  I've seen it both ways!

Answer (score 0):

Either way is acceptable - it's a style issue. And by the way, your example isn't an acronym, it's an initialism or abbreviation. Acronyms are read out as words, like NASA, but not PLC or CIA.