# Plural form of Abbreviation Ending in O

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

My company deals in Purchase Orders.

For years they have referred to multiple purchase orders as POs.  It seems, the proper spelling would be POes, because a P-O is referred to as a noun by everyone in the company, even though it is an abbreviated form of Purchase Order.

Which is correct?  POs or POes ?

Comment: See FumbleFingers' [answer to a similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58994/13812)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PO is an abbreviation, it just gets an **-s**: **POs**. It's not the same as *potato* or *tomato*, which would get *-es*.

See [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/apostrophe#apostrophes_showing_plurals?view=uk): "Just add -s (or -es, if the noun in question forms its plural with -es). For example: MPs ... An apostrophe should never be used to form the plural of ordinary nouns, names, abbreviations, or numerical dates."

So: POs because *order* takes a simple *s*. And not *PO's* with an apostrophe.

However, I believe the Chicago Manual of Style does advocate using an apostrophe (but I don't have a reference for that, if it's online at all).

Comment: So if the abbreviation was, say, GT for green tomato, are you saying the plural should be GTes? Or black ox becomes BOen? Looks wrong to me. Do you have any real-life examples where -es (or other non-s) us added?

Comment: See Alex B.'s answer for a CMOS reference: apostrophe only used for lowercase letters such as x's.

Comment: @Hugo: I wondered about quoting the whole thing. I can't say I agree with their reckoning on -es, and I find it difficult to think of real-world examples. Even "Co" for "Company" would look awkward as "Coes". Perhaps what Oxford published there is now anachronistic. There are other conventions too: in Canon Law, if you abbreviate *Canon* as *Can* then an acceptable plural is *Cann*, and that method can be used with others as well.

Comment: Reading the Oxford page, it's a page about when to add apostrophes, not specifically about how to pluralise abbreviations. I don't think they're suggesting at all that plural **abbreviations** should ever have *-es*. They're saying add *-s* (without apostrophe) to make a plural noun, or *-es* (without apostrophe) if the noun is made plural with *-es*.

Answer (score 1):

*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (1985) clearly states that **abbreviations** (understood broadly) **get an -s** (or 's, which was much commoner in the past).  Section 5.81 (V)

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (16 th. ed.) says that "**abbreviations usually form the plural by adding *s***. To aid comprehension, lowercase letters form the plural with an apostrophe and an *s*." (Section 7.14)

UFOs, CEOs, CFOs, CBOs, IRAs, URLs, BSs, MAs, PhDs etc. but x's and y's

The only exception I'm aware of is OSes.

Comment: Do you have a reference to show OSes is an exception? An answer (linked in the question comments) says OSs is most common

Answer (score 0):

It is POs, or more correctly P.O.s, since the plural is for the abbreviated word rather than the word "PO".

Comment: Can you please give a reference?

Comment: There are only a few instances where "...os" is wrong and "...oes" must be used, and those words are already established. [ESL @ About.com](http://bit.ly/JR2Uvc). Since "PO" (in this question) is not a word and has not been established to be one that must use the "es" it would use a single "s".

Comment: I agree it is POs, but adding periods to abbreviations is somewhat old-fashioned in these acronym-heavy times.