# Defining an acronym when using the plural of the term?

Tags: acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

I am defining an acronym which will be substituted for some unwieldy term in a document.

> One thing Gary has talked extensively about is his inclination towards
>   extracting domain objects into Plain Ruby Objects (PRO).

The trouble is that the first time I use the unwieldy term (Plain Ruby Object), it is plural. However, the acronym is more useful in the singular.

Should I just hold off defining the acronym until I use its singular form further down the page?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. I see that you are asking something a little different, but I think the answer about how to pluralize the acronym will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either recast the first use of the full expansion into the singular, or else write the acronym in the plural.

- One thing Gary has talked extensively about is his inclination to extract a domain object into a Plain Ruby Object (PRO).
- One thing Gary has talked extensively about is his inclination to extract domain objects into Plain Ruby Objects (PROs).