# What is the correct way to define an acronym when its first appearance is plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms, initialisms

The question and answers posed in [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym) deals very nicely with acronym (and possibly initialism) usage. What about the case when you are defining the acronym?

For example:

1. ...automated teller machine (ATM)... - Easy enough.
2. ...automated teller machines (ATM)... ?
3. ...automated teller machines (ATMs)... ?

If the singular form will be used later then option 2 seems poor.  Generally option 3 appears to be best, but is it clear to the reader that we will write the singular form as "ATM"?

This idea is touched upon in [Defining an acronym when using the plural of the term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76557/defining-an-acronym-when-using-the-plural-of-the-term) but it is not complete.

Comment: Off topic (writing advice request). Suggest migrating to [writers.se].

Comment: Have a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with RyeBread here (sorry) -- if the acronym is a normal one in all caps, and the plural is given with a lowercase *s*, as in your *ATMs*, then your option 3 is correct - the change of case distinguishes the *s* from the *ATM*, avoiding confusion, while putting the singular form in brackets next to a plural makes it look like the singular acronym is equivalent to the plural long form.  An example from my field: [High-electron-mobility transistors (HEMTs)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-396X%28200105%29185:1%3C85::AID-PSSA85%3E3.0.CO;2-U/abstract), though personally I would have spelt out the long-form with initial caps.  Now with the example this is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that the correct plural is ATMs which leaves room for an ATM to signal possession with an apostrophe, i.e. "Hey, this ATM's touch screen is broken."

Comment: ...or even *These ATMs' touch screens are broken*