# Apostrophe and plurals of abbreviations

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, apostrophe, errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

I was in Middlesbrough yesterday and spotted:

**CJ’s Cafe**

So far, so good, I thought. A selection of the delights within were listed:

> Pizzas      Parmo’s      Breakfasts

The second, on the face of it, looks like a standard [greengrocer’s apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greengrocer%27s_apostrophe#Greengrocers.27_apostrophes), surprising in a sign where everything else is correct.

But *parmo* is an abbreviation for *parmesan*.

Is it correct to use an apostrophe there to indicate missing letters? Or would one normally expect to see *parmos*?

When forming other words from *parmesan* one would write *parmesanish* or *parmesany*. Would one then write *parmoish* and *parmoey* or *parmo’ish* and *parmo’y*?

Comment: *Parmo* is not an abbreviation of Parmesan but the [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmo), derived from *Parmesan*, of a dish; so, Yes, one would "expect to see *parmos*" in the plural. If I had occasion to employ nonce-constructions with *-ish* or *-y* I would write them as *parmo-ish* and *parmo-y* to clarify the structure.

Comment: Hmmm... you're not saying you're surprised by a grammatical error on a [restaurant sign](http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn259/dueeyenoewe/Spelling/TheirBurritos.jpg), are you? :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Parmo* is not an abbreviation of *parmesan*. (“Parm.” would be.) *Parmo* is a coined word, more like a nickname or diminutive, having an "-o" suffix like you might say “Johnno” for “Jonathan”. As such you would not need the apostrophe.