# Use of Apostrophes - FAQs vs FAQ's

Tags: word-usage, apostrophe

Is it also correct to say FAQ's as some sites like http://transition.fcc.gov/oet/rfsafety/rf-faqs.html refer? Or is FAQs the right and correct way to say it?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate, but I might have an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FAQ is an acronym for Frequently Asked Questions.

It's not possessive, not a contraction, doesn't have any foreign origins and is not used to indicate stress, so I write FAQs. For more information consult your favorite style manual or the thread linked in the comment above about the more general case:
[What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Comment: Thanks -- its a duplicate as coleopterist and you mention. Sorry, should have searched better before posting.

Comment: Foreign origins? *Waltz's* pretty much died out a long time ago, while *CD's* are lingering (though probably without much longer to live either).

Comment: I'm thinking more like calques, loanwords and transliterations where the word stays in the singular when it comes to foreign origins... Ch'olti', to pick something random out of Wikipedia--Of course that one might just be a substitute for other diacritical marks...dunno, but good point on the waltzes case--I'm into tango now...FAQs is interesting though because it's not just a case of the p's and q's--*Questions* is already plural so it's either the sets of FAQs or Qs stands for questions.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the old rule of using *'s* to pluralise loan-words ending in a vowel, *s*, *z*, *ch* or *sh*, which I should imagine is pretty safely dead now. C.D.'s used to be pretty much *the* standard, though is close to dead. Mention-plurals like "Do's and don'ts" still sometimes happen (with the added complication of avoiding two apostrophes close together), but more frequent ability to italicise means we can use that to make the same distinction clear without the need for it.

Comment: When using FAQs, wouldn't the Qs be a contraction of Questions (as it is already plural)?  In which case wouldn't that need an apostrophe?

Comment: @pete - The statement "FAQ" is an acronym, rather than an abbreviation, which I feel implies that the "Qs" isn't a contraction.