# What is the correct way to form a demonym from an acronym?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, demonyms

For instance, what is the equivalent of *New Yorker* when using the acronym (*NY* or *N.Y.* instead of *New York*)?

Comment: I don’t think this is common or codified enough in the English language that there is really a _correct_ way. I would most likely say an _NY’er_ (or a _US’er_, _PRC’er_, _LA’er_, etc.) … but others might think differently.

Comment: I suspect you're right. I suppose I'm wondering about the *most correct* or *least silly* way to do it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't disagree, but I think most US folks would skip the apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's formalized, but this is akin to how one forms the plural of acronyms. For example, compact discs: CDs or CD's?

Since the apostrophe denotes possession, it's more often correct to omit it when merely pluralizing, though there are some corner cases:

> The Chicago Manual of Style has an interesting way to address this:
>   They omit the apostrophe, unless there are periods in the
>   abbreviation. So this would give you ATMs, or alternately A.T.M.'s.
>   (A.T.M.s looks weird.) [chicagomanualofstyle.org,
>   "Plurals"](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Plurals.html?old=Plurals11.html)
>
> The 2009 AP Stylebook's "plurals" entry has no section on acronyms,
>   but mentions "VIPs", I can't find anything addressing how to
>   specifically pluralize acronyms. (The "abbreviations and acronyms"
>   section is also of no help.)
>   [[source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)]

The same holds for demonyms, in my opinion: NYer looks more natural (or less unnatural, anyway) than NY'er.

That said, it still seems very unusual to use demonyms in this way (LA-lino? LAXer? PDXer.. hmm... for some reason it seems more natural with airport codes), so proceed with caution.

Comment: I disagree that this is akin to forming plurals of acronyms (and the possessive is a clitic, rather than a suffix, so it is not really relevant here). It ‘feels’ more akin to conjugating verbs made from acronyms to me, where an inconsistent hodgepodge of hyphens and apostrophes are employed—but never zero. For example, you’ll find in both dictionaries and style guides forms such as _OD’(e)d_ and _OD-ing/OD’ing_, but not (that I have found, at least) _*ODd_ or _*ODing_. To me, _NY’er_ looks more natural than _NYer_.

Comment: Why in the world would anyone want to say NYer? It involves three syllables, the same number as New Yorker. So why not say the whole thing?

Comment: @WS2 this for written (not spoken) word, mostly

Comment: Also, this was just an example and there are other times where the acronym, for whatever reason, is more identifiable than the original name.