# What is the correct abbreviation for the plural "Quantitative Trait Loci" — "QTL" or "QTLs"?

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms

Strictly speaking, both the biological term *Quantitative Trait Locus* and its plural *Quantitative Trait Loci* can be abbreviated as *QTL*. However, one often reads the abbreviations *QTL* and *QTLs*. Is the *-s* behind *QTL* wrong or correct? After all, it's not "Locuses".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Answer (score 2):

For a given abbreviation *XYZ* (doesn't mean anything, I'm making up an abbreviation so I can generalise), the plural is *XYZs* if the plural can be meaningfully and usefully distinguished from the singular, and *XYZ* if it cannot.

An example of the latter, is if *XYZ* abbreviates an abstract noun, or is already plural (that is, there is no such thing as a single *XYZ*).

It would once have been *XYZ's* but that style is now so old-fashioned as to be obsolete and a risk of being perceived as a mistake.

There are two overlapping exceptions.

1. If there's a separate abbreviation for the plural.
2. If the abbreviation is a traditional one, particularly those that come from Latin abbreviations.

An example in the overlap would be that where the abbreviation for "page" is *p.* (borrowing the abbreviation of *pagina*), the abbreviation for "pages" is *pp.* (borrowing the abbreviation of *paginae*).

From all the above, we would expect the plural to be *QTLs* unless there was a good reason for those who particularly care about Quantitative Trait Loci to not particularly care about an individual Quantitative Trait Locus.

Answer (score 1):

I would let euphony be your guide on this one. While QTL may stand for Quantitative Trait Loci, people will read it as QTL and pluralise it accordingly.

As a comparison, the plural of FAQ is FAQs, even though Frequently Asked Questions is itself plural.