# Is the apostrophe always necessary when denoting the number of individual items that are usually grouped together such as M&Ms?

Tags: punctuation

Which is correct: I ate the M&M's or I ate the M&Ms? With or without the apostrophe?

Comment: This is really a matter of style, so the answer depends on which style guide you are following.

Comment: M&M's is the actual name of the candy, so in this case, M&M's would be the correct use.  M&Ms would simply be a mispelling of the candy's name.  In other cases, such as with letters (M's vs Ms, or B's vs Bs), using an apostrophe may be a matter of style.

Comment: Who cares about the history of people who eat junk food.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, an apostrophe is used with plurals only when leaving it out would cause confusion. For example, in the sentence *All the students got A's*, you'd use an apostrophe to make *A* plural because otherwise it'd be the word *as.* *M&Ms*, on the other hand, is clear in meaning without the apostrophe, so using one isn't necessary.

Comment: Tell the M&M's manufacturers that.

Answer (score 1):

Your M&Ms example is just a regular plural so no apostrophe.

Comment: Hey, another *Jim!*

Comment: Someone was once taken to court for spelling _Biro_ with a small b. _Lloyd's_ and _Lloyds_ are very different organisations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the question. If there existed a candy named M&M, the correct plural would be M&Ms.  However, when the candy is m&m, writing m&ms would be confusing.  Is it em-and-em-es? I would use the plural form m&m's for clarity.  Just as it says on the bag.