# Is there a use for apostrophes aside from possession?

Tags: verbs, apostrophe

My teacher has said that the statement

> The working thesis statement reflects how the characters' help
>   establish the religious allegory.

is 'grammatically' correct, with *help* acting as a verb, not a noun.
I have been taught that this is not the correct use of apostrophes, but he says that it is correct – that there is an alternate use of apostrophes that few people use. Is he correct?

Comment: What uses of the apostrophe have you found on ELU? (Though I'd say this example is unacceptable. 'Few' might equal 'one' here, and acceptability is usage-driven.)

Comment: No. If one role of the characters is to offer assistance to establishing the allegory, then "characters help" and they do so without an apostrophe.

Comment: Your example is *definitely* invalid, but almost everyone would accept "apostrophised plurals" in, for example, ***mind your p's and q's***. See [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/)

Comment: ... and some accept an apostrophe in a word that could be considered even more outlandish without. _We had the misfortune to run across our ex's at both the Christmas and the New Year do's_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "help" is used as the verb in the sentence, the apostrophe at the end of "characters" makes no sense that I can determine.

If help is a noun and is modified by "characters'", then "establish" needs to become 3rd person ,"establishes", to be correct.

If "the characters help establish" there is no problem.

> The working thesis statement reflects how the characters' help establish the religious allegory.

is not correct.

> The working thesis statement reflects how the characters help establish the religious allegory.

would be fine. The "characters help establish".

> The working thesis statement reflects how the characters' help establishes the religious allegory.

is OK. The help of the characters establishes.