# What's the correct British English plural form of TV? Is it TVs or TV's? Thank you!

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english, acronyms, initialisms

e.g. I have two **TVs** VS I have two **TV's**. Which one is the correct form in British English?

Comment: I don't think there's a rule specifically for TVs, but more generally with an initialism it's illogical to use an apostrophe but it's also very common, so...

Comment: One only uses an apostrophe (as a separator) when it would be unclear whether the plural **s** is part of the abbrevation. One way round it is to use the full word – televisions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym / initialism?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym-initialism)

Comment: The plural is /ti:vi:z/.